# ActiveMQ - preserve consumers during a failover

Tags: activemq-classic, failover, message-listener

Broker URL

```
failover:(tcp://broker1:61616,tcp://broker2:61616)?randomize=false&jms.useAsyncSend=false&jms.dispatchAsync=false&maxReconnectAttempts=2&maxReconnectDelay=100
```

I register a message listener on the active broker:

```
  Destination destQueue = new ActiveMQQueue("queue");
  MessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(destQueue);
  messageConsumer.setMessageListener(consumer);
```

During a failover the consumer disapears and is not re-registered on the second broker. Can you give me some light how could I register the listener on the other broker automatically upon failover?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found out - the problem was because I used PooledConnectionFactory for listener's code. Replaced with ActiveMQConnectionsFactory and it worked.